# how can we write SQL query return data from multiple tables

Tags: sql

[question tables and required output are there in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70HWx.png) 
how can we find the employee id, name who don't have address in address table or address is null?

how can we write query for this requirement?
please help me?

Comment: LEFT JOIN the emp_address table. Check for null address.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` might help.

```
SQL> with
  2  emp (id, name) as
  3    (select 1, 'abc' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'mno' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'xyz' from dual
  6    ),
  7  emp_address (id, address) as
  8    (select 1, 'bangalore' from dual union all
  9     select 3, null from dual
 10    )
 11  select e.id, e.name
 12  from emp e
 13  where not exists (select null
 14                    from emp_address a
 15                    where a.id = e.id
 16                      and a.address is not null
 17                   )
 18  order by e.id;

        ID NAM
---------- ---
         2 mno
         3 xyz

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of finding it.

**Outer Join**

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT E.* FROM 
EMP E LEFT JOIN  EMP_ADDRESS EA
ON (E.ID = EA.ID))
WHERE EA.ADDRESS IS NOT NULL;
```

**Not Exists**

```
SELECT * FROM EMP
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM EMP_ADDRESS EA
WHERE E.ID = EA.ID
AND EA.ADDRESS IS NOT NULL);
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
 SELECT *
    FROM emp
    Inner JOIN emp_address
    ON emp.emp_id= emp_address.emp_id where emp_address.Id=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo to get the above output:

```
create table emp
(id NUMBER,
name varchar2(100));

insert into emp values(1,'abc');
insert into emp values(2,'mno');
insert into emp values(3,'xyz');

create table emp_address
(id NUMBER,
address varchar2(100));

insert into emp_address values(1,'banglore');
insert into emp_address values(3,NULL);
commit;

select * from emp;
select * from emp_address;

SELECT ID,NAME
FROM emp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM emp_address WHERE emp.ID=emp_address.ID AND address IS NOT NULL)
;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you must relate the tables. The tables must be in this way

### emp

id   name 
1    abc 
2    mno 
3    xyz

### emp_address

id     address          id_emp 
1       banglore          2 
3       null                 3

if you want null addresses to come out then select

select e.nombre, ea.address from emp e, emp_address ea where e.id = ea.id_emp;

if you don't want the null addresses to come out then select it

select e.nombre, ea.address from emp e, emp_address ea where e.id = ea.id_emp and ea.address is not null;

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query for your desired results:

**select e.id 
from emp e, emp_address ea
where e.id = ea.id
and ea.address is not null**

Your desired output in your question is also not correct. ID (2) with name (mno) should not be displayed as id(2) is not present in the emp_address table.